# Ruby modules mixin using include and extend - how it works?

Tags: ruby, module, include, extend, mixins

Following are the code snippets:

**Module: ActiveSupport::Concern**

```
    module ActiveSupport
      module Concern
        def self.extended(base)
          base.instance_variable_set("@_dependencies", [])
        end

        def append_features(base)
          if base.instance_variable_defined?("@_dependencies")
            base.instance_variable_get("@_dependencies") << self
            return false
          else
            return false if base < self
            @_dependencies.each { |dep| base.send(:include, dep) }
            super
            base.extend const_get("ClassMethods") if const_defined?("ClassMethods")
            base.send :include, const_get("InstanceMethods") if const_defined?("InstanceMethods")
            base.class_eval(&@_included_block) if instance_variable_defined?("@_included_block")
          end
        end

        def included(base = nil, &block)
          if base.nil?
            @_included_block = block
          else
            super
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

**Custom Module: GeneralScopes**

```
    module GeneralScopes
        extend ActiveSupport::Concern

        included do
          scope :reverse_order_by_date, :order => "date DESC"
          scope :recent, lambda { |count| reverse_order_by_date.limit(count) }
        end
    end
```

**Custom Class: User**

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      include GeneralScopes
    end
```

**Usage:**

```
    User.recent(5) => Prints the recent five User instances available in database
```

I have following questions in context of above shown code snippets:

1) **include(MODULE_NAME(s))**. 
*include is a private instance method of Module and this method is invoked by **self** implicitly*.
    So what does **self** represent in the class body? 
    In the class's instance method **self** represents the current object.
    In the class's class method **self** represents the class's Class object.

How does this `include <MODULE_NAME>` syntax from class body works?

2) extend(MODULE_NAME(s))

### Quoted from "The Ruby Programming Language" by David Flanagan and Yukihiro Matsumoto (Oreilly), Chapter 7 Classes and Modules

> *Object.extend.This method makes the instance methods of the
>   specified  module or modules into singleton methods of the receiver
>   object.(And if the receiver  object is a Class instance, then the
>   methods of the receiver become the class methods  of that class)*

I am unable to understand this in context of my **GeneralScopes** module shown above.

3)

```
    module GeneralScopes
        extend ActiveSupport::Concern

        included do
          scope :reverse_order_by_date, :order => "date DESC"
          scope :recent, lambda { |count| reverse_order_by_date.limit(count) }
        end
    end
```

module GeneralScopes I assume is invoking the ActiveSupport::Concern module's instance method "included(base = nil, &block)".How does this invocation of an instance method from module body work? Which object acts as the receiver when

```
     included do
          scope :reverse_order_by_date, :order => "date DESC"
          scope :recent, lambda { |count| reverse_order_by_date.limit(count) }
     end
```

is executed?

4) ActiveSupport::Concern module's instance method "included(base = nil, &block)"

```
        def included(base = nil, &block)
          if base.nil?
            @_included_block = block
          else
            super
          end
        end
```

Here **super** is used.This **super** works in context of User class or ActiveSupport::Concern module? To which class
   the control goes when **super** is executed?

*It would be a great help if anybody can make me understand the control flow executed or point me to any relevant resources explaining the concepts related to questions I have.*

Comment: http://opensoul.org/blog/archives/2011/02/07/concerning-activesupportconcern/

Answer (score 5):

1) `include` makes the module's methods available as *instance methods* of the class whereas `extend` makes the module's methods available as *class methods*. So `self` refers to either the instance or the class:

```
module M
  def foo
    puts self
  end
end

class A
  include M
end

A.new.foo # => #<A:0x007fcefa18e270> ('self' refers to the instance)

class B
  extend M
end

B.foo # => B ('self' refers to the class)
```

2) `extend ActiveSupport::Concern` makes `ActiveSupport::Concern`'s methods available to `GeneralScopes` so you can call the `included` method.

3) The block is assigned to `@_included_block` and evaluated from within `append_features` (`base.class_eval(&@_included_block)`) which is called when `GeneralScopes` is included by User. From the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-append_features):

> When this module is included in another, Ruby calls `append_features` in this module, passing it the receiving module in mod.

4) `super` refers to `ActiveSupport::Concern`'s parent, so `Module`'s [`included`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-included) is called.